# How to override verification email function in dj-rest-auth and all-auth?

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I want to override the email verification method and put it in a Celery queue as it takes up quite some time (2-3 seconds) for the email to send.
My question is, where can I find the function with sends the email?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django Celery Email to send your emails via a celery queue: https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-email/

If you have a higher volume that needs to be send, you can also user Django-Mailer: https://pypi.org/project/django-mailer/

These plugins will replace your default email backend and all emails will be processed via them.